# SQL Server CE instead of SQL Server Express

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sqlite, sql-server-ce, sql-server-express

When creating a new ASP.NET MVC application in VS2010 you get Account (Simple Membership Database) database in SQL Server Express format.

Since I have problems with database migration / configuration on my remote host I decided to switch to SQL Server CE.

Question: how can I migrate from SQL Server Express to SQL Server CE? Tried to re-create tables from SQL Server Express in SQL Server CE but my approach to create names starting with 'dbo.' i.e. failed (used CompactView software)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[webpages_UsersInRoles]
(
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RoleId] [int] NOT NULL
);
```

So I created tables without 'dbo.' and it does not work.

Question: what is the best approach to migrate a simple membership database from SQL Server Express to SQL Server CE?

Question2: Is migration from SQL Server Express to SQLite easy?

Thank you!

Comment: Instead of `[dbo].[webpages_UsersInRoles]` I used `[dbo.webpages_UsersInRoles]` and managed to create tables. It did not solve the exception raised by `SimpleMembershipInitializer`

Comment: Maybe you can use my old Tool here http://sqlcemembership.codeplex.com/ - will create the database file and tables for you

Comment: Thank you ErikEJ, I think that my problem was probably based on the fact that I tried to `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection` to database which was already connected by another database context. Now I have two databases, one for my data and another for SimpleMembership